# Rails error "wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using a scope to filter my results :

```
@hotels = @hotels.type(params[:hotel_type]) unless params[:hotel_type].blank?
```

with

```
scope :type, lambda { |type|
  self.scoped.where('hotel_type_id IN ( ? )', type.join(', ')) unless type.blank?
}
```

And params[:hotel_type] = ["2","3"]

Anyone can help me? I think it's because it's an array but i don't know how to fix this.

Thank you

Comment: You should be able pass in `type` without the `join` because the SQL escaping should take care of it for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i think you cant name your scope `type`, i'd name it `by_type`

Comment: Sometimes reserved words sneak up and bite you like this.

Comment: Yes, i didn't think so but it seems logical!

Comment: Yesterday I tried to name a column 'type' and that didn't work either.

Comment: Type is used in single table inheritance to name a attribute in order to use same table for diff classes.